# Django ORM: Retrieve first measurement from every day in big dataset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have a Django project about temperature measurements. I'm using PostgreSQL as database backend. Let's say my model is:

```
class TemperatureMeasurement(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=False)
```

I've taken measurements every minute for the last 6 months or so, meaning I have about ~270k rows in this table. I'm writing an API which should return the first temperature record for every day, for a given date range. I have something like this:

```
def TemperatureBetween(APIView):
    # ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date_from = datetime.strptime(kwargs['date_from'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        date_to = datetime.strptime(kwargs['date_to'], '%Y-%m-%d')

        all_measurements = TemperatureMeasurement.objects.filter(
            time__gte=date_from,
            time__lt=date_to,
        ).order_by('time')

        r = []
        current_day = date_from

        while current_day < date_to:
            day_measurement = all_measurements.filter(
                time__gte=current_day,
            ).first()
            r.append([day_measurement.time, day_measurement.temperature])
            current_day += timedelta(hours=24)

        return Response(r)
```

I'm aware that this approach if probably far from being optimal, because as I understand, I'm making at least as many database queries as days in the time range (that's also what Django Debug Toolbar tells me). I've read about Django's `Q()` objects, but I'm unsure about how I can use them in this case. I've thought something like:

```
        # ...
        query = Q()
        while current_day < date_to:
            query |= Q(time__gte=current_day).first()
            current_day += timedelta(hours=24)

        temperature_measurements = TemperatureMeasurement.objects.filter(query)
        # ... process data...
```

But this doesn't work since `Q()` object has no attribute 'first'. Is there any way I could optimize this query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay

daily_first_measurement = (TemperatureMeasurement.objects
                           .filter(time__gte=date_from, time__lt=date_to)
                           .annotate(day=TruncDay(time))
                           .order_by('day', 'time')
                           .distinct('day')
)
```

This will return the first record of `TemperatureMeasurement` for each day in the range from `date_from` to `date_to`. For others reading this, postgresql is necessary as the underlying database for this query (to take advantage of `distinct`).